# PHP unlink symlink

Tags: php, symlink, delete-file, unlink

when I create under windows a symlink (didn't test it yet under linux) and want to delete/unlink it again (I tried it with the unlink() - function), it always delete the symlink + original file. But I just want to delete the symlink. Isn't there any function for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12288764/3910083

unlink() is the correct approach

code snippet from a project of mine, to only delete if it was a symlink

```
if(file_exists($linkfile)) {
    if(is_link($linkfile)) {
        unlink($linkfile);
    } else {
        exit("$linkfile exists but not symbolic link\n");
    }
}
```

readlink(), returns the target of a link, you can run unlink on that

```
if(is_link($linkfile)) {
      $target = readlink($linkfile)
      unlink($target)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename the symbolic link to something like "my_link" in order to
   reuse the same PHP file.
2. Create the PHP file with the appropriate code. I used "unlink.php". Simple and easy to remember.
3. Upload the PHP file to the directory containing the link.
4. Type in the URL to the file.

The result is that the file disappears without a trace.

```
<?php
unlink ('my_link');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you are using soft link, not hard links

check the usage of Mklink from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: i created the link with the symlink() - function

Comment: What windows system are you using
XP/VISTA/7 or Server 2000/3/8?

Answer (score 0):

On linux, to be safe I would just go with

```
shell_exec('rm ' . $file);
```

Answer (score -2):

Read this:-

http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php

try this:-

```
symlink($target, $link);
unlink($link);
unlink($target);
```

Comment: i want to delete the symlink, why i should create a new link then?