# Deleting Symbolic Links in PHP

Tags: php

What is the proper way to delete symbolic links, preserving what they link to? 
What is the proper way to delete what they link to? Which would [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) do?  There seems to be some [ambiguity](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52176).

Through a little testing, symbolic links respond to [is_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) and [is_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) according to what they point to, as well as returning `true` to [is_link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-link.php).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`unlink()` is the correct approach

code snippet from a project of mine, to only delete if it was a symlink

```
if(file_exists($linkfile)) {
    if(is_link($linkfile)) {
        unlink($linkfile);
    } else {
        exit("$linkfile exists but not symbolic link\n");
    }
}
```

readlink(), returns the target of a link, you can run unlink on that

```
if(is_link($linkfile)) {
      $target = readlink($linkfile)
      unlink($target)
}
```